# Order Axiom explanation

Tags: calculus, real-numbers

Can someone explain to me how to go about solving this axiom. I don't fully understand axioms, so I'm having problems.

Let $x, y, z$ belong to the real number system and let > be an order operation on R. The following statements are expected to be true.

O1- If $x>y$, then $x + z > y + z$

O2- If $x>y$ and $z>0$, then $x.z > y.z$

03- If $x>y$ and $y>z$, then $x>z$

O4- Either $x>y$ or $x=y$ or $y>x$

Prove that if $x>y$ and $z<0$, then $x.z<y.z$

Comment: You should compare $-z$ to 0 depending on the position of $z$ to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to prove that :

> $(y<x∧z<0) → (x∗z)<(y∗z)$.

---

Consider $y<x$ and $z<0$ and assume that :  $\lnot ((x∗z)<(y∗z))$.

From axiom O4 : $x < y ∨ (x = y ∨ y < x)$ we have that :

> either $(x∗z)=(y∗z)$ or $(y∗z)<(x∗z)$.

---

Assume *(i)* : $(x∗z)=(y∗z)$.

By properties of product, if $z \ne 0, (x ∗ z) = (y ∗ z) → x = y$; thus, we conclude with : $x = y$.

By substitution into assumption $y < x$, we get :

> $x < x$ : contradiction.

---

Assume now *(ii)* : $(y∗z)<(x∗z)$.

We have that : $x < 0 → 0 < (−x)$.

Thus, from assumption $z < 0$ we have $0 < (-z)$.

Using axiom O2 : $(y < x ∧ 0 < z) → (y ∗ z) < (x ∗ z)$ we get :

> $(y ∗ (-z)) < (x ∗ (-z))$.

We have assumed : $(y∗z)<(x∗z)$; thus  $(y∗z) + (y ∗ (-z)) < (x∗z) + (y ∗ (-z))$ from axiom O1 : $y < x → (y + z) < (x + z)$.

By *distributive law* : $x ∗ (y + z) = (x ∗ y) + (x ∗ z)$ and the fact that : $x + (−x) = 0$, we have :

> $(y∗z) + (y ∗ (-z)) = (y ∗(z + (-z)) = (y ∗ 0) < (x∗z) + (y ∗ (-z))$.

But we know that : $x ∗ 0 = 0$; thus :

> $0 < (x∗z) + (y ∗ (-z))$.

In the same way, from $(y ∗ (-z)) < (x ∗ (-z))$ we get : $(y ∗ (-z)) + (x∗z) < (x ∗ (-z)) + (x∗z)$, by axiom O1, and again we use distributivity to have :

> $(y ∗ (-z)) + (x∗z) < 0$.

Thus, from : $0 < (x∗z) + (y ∗ (-z))$ and $(y ∗ (-z)) + (x∗z) < 0$, with axiom O3 : $(y < x ∧ z < y) → z < x$, we conclude with :

> $0 < 0$ : contradiction.

---

Resuming : with assumptions $y<x$, $z<0$ and $\lnot ((x∗z)<(y∗z))$ we have two cases : *(i)* and *(ii)*.

In both cases we have derived a contradiction. Thus :

> > if $y<x$ and $z<0$, then $(x∗z) < (y∗z)$.